# Mapping a derived class with additional collection property in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to use the table-per-subclass (which fluent-nhibernate automaps by default) with a class structure like the following:

```
public class Product 
{
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Title{ get; set; }
}

public class ProductPackage : Product
{
    public ProductPackage(){ Includes = new List<Product>(); }
    public virtual IList<Prodcut> Includes{ get; private set; }

    [EditorBrowsable( EditorBrowsableState.Never )]
    public class ProductPackageAutoOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<ProductPackage>
    {
        public void Override( AutoMap<ProductPackage> mapping )
        {
            mapping.HasManyToMany( x => x.Includes )
                .WithTableName( "IncludesXProduct" )
                .WithParentKeyColumn( "ProductId" )
                .WithChildKeyColumn( "IncludesProductId" )
                .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of adding a new table "IncludesXProduct" to represent the many-to-many mapping, it adds a property "ProductPackageId" to the Product table. Of course persisting to this schema doesn't work.

Have I missed something simple or is this type of thing not really supported by NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with NHibernate.  Unfortunately my fluent syntax isn't very good, but it looks like FNH is somehow regarding the relationship as a many-to-one rather than a many-to-many.

If you tag your question with "fluent-nhibernate" then you may get more knowledgeable people answering.